# get value input text with button angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to get the text of an input text and saving it in a variable using a button. To use it as a parameter in a query in firebase.

.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value1" id="textCI" placeholder="C.I." >
```

component.ts

<--ResultCI =valor input text-->

```
 buscarCI(){
    let query=null;
    query=this.servicio.getUsuarioFiltro(this.ResultCI);
    query.snapshotChanges()
      .map(changes=>{
        return changes.map(c=>({key:c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))
      }).subscribe(contactos =>{
        this.contactos=contactos
      });
  }
```

Comment: This for angularjs or angular? If angularjs please update the tag

Comment: This is explained in the documentation and many tutorials on the subject... See, for example, [the section marked "Template syntax" on Angular's cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet), and [the Forms section of their Guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the angularjs syntax which is ng-model, instead you should use **`[(ngModel)]`**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value1" id="textCI" placeholder="C.I." >
```

you should be able to access in the component with **`this.value1`**

Comment: @CristianLagla Might be you forget to import `FormsModule` in `modules.ts`