# how to get input number value when button is clicked

Tags: angular, button, input, ngfor

I'm not sure how I can get the value of the button... this is my code

```
<p *ngFor = "let product of ProductsDetails; let i = index">
   <input type="number" value={{cartProducts[i].amount}} class="quantInput"> 
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="changeBTN">change</button>
</p>
```

note: the amount of buttons & inputs is dynamic so I can't have a variable that will hold the input's value or I just don't know how to do it

Comment: answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203795/get-value-input-text-with-button-angular-7

Comment: this would work if the buttons and inputs were not dynamic... for this to work i need to hold a variable for each input but i cant know how many inputs i will have so this answer is wrong

Comment: That would be easy. You already have everything nested inside an ngFor loop and an index i to distinct each specific element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <p *ngFor = "let product of ProductsDetails; let i = index">
     <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="values[i]" value={{cartProducts[i].amount}} class="quantInput"> 
     <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="changeBTN" (click)="doSomethingWithInputValue(i)" >change</button>
   </p>
```

**ts file**

```
values: any[];

//initialize array when you have loaded productDetails
ProductDetails.forEach((productDetail) => {
     this.values.push({});
});


public doSomethingWithInputValue(index){

    const currentInputValue = this.values[index];
    ...do everything you want with this value here
    }
```